# How to make div pop up on hovering mouse in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I am using the code written [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6uSwA/).

```
$('a.popper').hover(function (e) {...});

    <script src="jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var moveLeft = 0;
    var moveDown = 0;
    $('a.popper').hover(function (e) {

        var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
        $(target).show();
        moveLeft = $(this).outerWidth();
        moveDown = ($(target).outerHeight() / 2);
    }, function () {
        var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
        if (!($("a.popper").hasClass("show"))) {
            $(target).hide();
        }
    });

    $('a.popper').mousemove(function (e) {
        var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));

        leftD = e.pageX + parseInt(moveLeft);
        maxRight = leftD + $(target).outerWidth();
        windowLeft = $(window).width() - 40;
        windowRight = 0;
        maxLeft = e.pageX - (parseInt(moveLeft) + $(target).outerWidth() + 20);

        if (maxRight > windowLeft && maxLeft > windowRight) {
            leftD = maxLeft;
        }

        topD = e.pageY - parseInt(moveDown);
        maxBottom = parseInt(e.pageY + parseInt(moveDown) + 20);
        windowBottom = parseInt(parseInt($(document).scrollTop()) + parseInt($(window).height()));
        maxTop = topD;
        windowTop = parseInt($(document).scrollTop());
        if (maxBottom > windowBottom) {
            topD = windowBottom - $(target).outerHeight() - 20;
        } else if (maxTop < windowTop) {
            topD = windowTop + 20;
        }

        $(target).css('top', topD).css('left', leftD);
    });
    $('a.popper').click(function (e) {
        var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
        if (!($(this).hasClass("show"))) {
            $(target).show();
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("show");
    });
</script>

        <div id="pop1" class="popbox">
 <h2>Job Info Search</h2>

 <h2>WRKNo : <input type="text"  /></h2>

 <h2>Result</h2>

<p>Customer Name :
    <input type="text" />
</p>
<p>Caller Number :
    <input type="text" />
</p>
<p>Complosed :
    <input type="text" />
</p>
<p>Cate :
    <input type="text" />
</p>
<p>Det :
    <input type="text" />
</p>
<p>Feedback :
    <input type="text" />
</p>
<p>WRKNo :
    <input type="text" />
</p>
```

This is a popbox test. Hover here to see how it works.

CSS

```
        .popbox {
display: none;
position: absolute;
z-index: 99999;
width: 400px;
padding: 10px;
background: #EEEFEB;
color: #000000;
border: 1px solid #4D4F53;
margin: 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);
```

}

```
.popbox h2 {
background-color: #4D4F53;
color: #E3E5DD;
font-size: 14px;
display: block;
width: 100%;
margin: -10px 0px 8px -10px;
padding: 5px 10px;
```

}

It's working fine there, but if I use the same code in asp.net it doesn't work. Nothing happens. Is there more workaround to be done to get it working in asp.net or this method is not at all supported with asp.net

How can I do the same thing in asp.net?

Thanks,

Comment: What does asp.net have to do with this code?  Show your aspx code in your post, you're probably missing something simple.

Comment: I am using the same code in asp.net.

Comment: have you checked whether you have linked Jquery in the page

Comment: When you use asp.net it adds extra to your html markup such as adding prefixes to your id's and so forth try opening developer tools and make sure your naming conventions match. You may have to use regex to select the obejcts needed. Assuming you are using asp controls on the page instead of html. Just a thought

Comment: that is not true for html controls

Comment: place your `jquery.js` within the `<head>` and above the `<body>`

Comment: jquesty.js is within <head> and above <body>

Comment: okay, its not true for html controls, I removed all the html controls and just kept the div with backgroung-color which is not working too

Comment: Put the javascript at the bottom of the page above the </body> tag and iot will work

Answer (score 0):

Like Rick said, the ASPX code would be useful. JavaScript and ASP don't always play nice, may need a ScriptManager.

Answer (score 0):

I had asked you to post your ASPX page but I guess you don't want to so all we can do is guess what you're problem is.  Try wrapping all of your script code inside document.ready().  If you still have problems, try opening your browser's console(F12) and see if you get any errors in the console.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

   var moveLeft = 0;
   var moveDown = 0;
   $('a.popper').hover(function (e) {

    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    $(target).show();
    moveLeft = $(this).outerWidth();
    moveDown = ($(target).outerHeight() / 2);
    }, function () {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    if (!($("a.popper").hasClass("show"))) {
        $(target).hide();
    }
    });

   ....rest of your code

 });
```